# How to search for a strings between two tokens in a directory in ubuntu terminal and save the output

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, grep

I'm looking for everything between the string "`gem '`" and the string "`'`" in a directory.

For example:

`gem 'mysql2'`

In the example above I would be looking for an output such as this:

`mysql2`

I have worked on couple of rails projects, so from their gem files, i want to make a list of all the gems which i have used so far.

It is important that I can also save the data output in a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
s="gem 'mysql2'"
awk -F"'" '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
mysql2
```

To save the output use:

```
var=$(awk -F"'" '{print $2}' <<< "$s")
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F"'"` - Uses `'` as field separator
- `print $2` prints 2nd field which is the string inside single quote

Same thing using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP "'\K[^']+" <<< "$s"
mysql2
```

Comment: how can i find this in a directory?

Comment: i used -r also for recursive search, `grep -roP "gem '\K[^']+"` this was the exact command used, this helped me. +1

Comment: You can also use `awk -F"'" '{print $2}' file` but `grep` has better support for recursive searches.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the other answer, there is another way to extract the string between two single quotes.

```
echo "gem 'mysql2'"|cut -d"'" -f2
```

The **explanation** is as follows,

```
cut -d"'" -f2
```

`cut` command will find 2nd field from the text `gem 'mysql2'` by using delimiter `'`.

The **output** will be as follows exactly,

```
mysql2
```

Here is what I have tried,

[image]